# Once spring mvc boilerplate project is setup, is python/RoR much faster to develop?

Tags: java, spring

I'm starting a new project, and wondering if I should try out python or ruby.

I am pretty new to java/hibernate myself actually (I' into .net, or was!).

It has taken a while to setup this IDEA spring mvc application with all the dependancies, logging, artifacts/modules etc etc.

But the bulk seems to be done now!

Now do you think going with python/ruby will still greatly improve my development time?

Comment: I dont know, but I doubt the "bulk is done", it looks like you are just getting started.

Comment: why not to try .NET ASP MVC framework if you are familiar with .NET?

Answer (score 3):

I have been working with the Play Framework recently and the productivity increase is excellent. It doesn't create boilerplate code, but requires much less code to be written through clever techniques.
If you are considering RoR, I would highly recommend taking a look at Play before you make a final choice.

http://www.playframework.org

Answer (score 0):

As with any toolset & framework, familiarity is what will give you power. Many frameworks reduce boilerplate and setup costs, but this is only part of what will slow you down.

At this stage I suggest you focus on what you have started. When you feel confident that you know the costs involved in the chosen framework, then try something new if you like. But splitting your focus will be the biggest killer to your productivity.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to struggle if you're new to anything.  The fact that you're unfamiliar with Java and Hibernate compared to what you know with .NET won't be improved by going with Python or Ruby if you don't know those, either.

Why aren't you writing this app in .NET if that's what you know?

Assuming that you still want to press on with something besides .NET, I'd recommend trying a framework to help with the boilerplate.  If you want Java, Spring and Hibernate - try Grails.  If you want Ruby - try RoR.  If you want Python - try Django.

The problem you'll have with all three is that if something goes wrong you may not be able to save yourself easily.  But that problem will be common with all three.

Comment: Hi duffymo, as an experienced java/.net developer, if you evaluate play framework, you'll probably prefer play instead of ror,grails,rails and django.

Comment: Maybe I'll find out for myself.  I already have an opinion about grails.  Aren't "ror" and "rails" the same thing?  Maybe you should tell us what your affiliation with Play is, if any.  It'll help to identify any biases you might have.